# How to call a function with values returned from other function

Tags: javascript

I have a main function from where I call other functions which are present in my project. In a function `getNumberOfShelves` I successfully get `numberOfBooks` and `numberOfShelves` values(console log works). But when I try to call the next function

```
createManyShelves(arr, numberOfBooks, numberOfShelves)
```

with these values I get 'undefined'. How could I fix it?

```js
var numberOfBooks;
var numberOfShelves;
var widthOfOneImage = 100;
var arr = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg']

window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  mainFunc()
});

function mainFunc() {
  getNumberOfShelves(arr, document.querySelector('.axis').clientWidth, widthOfOneImage);
  createManyShelves(arr, numberOfBooks, numberOfShelves)
}

function getNumberOfShelves(arra, width, imageWidth) {
  var numberOfBooks = (Math.floor(width / widthOfOneImage));
  var numberOfShelves = Math.ceil(arra.length / numberOfBooks);
  console.log(numberOfBooks, numberOfShelves); //work
  return numberOfBooks, numberOfShelves;
}

function createManyShelves(arra, books, shelves) {
  console.log(books, shelves); //doesn't work
}
```

Comment: You aren't using the return value from `getNumberOfShelves` (or returning the values properly in `getNumberOfShelves`)

Comment: `return numberOfBooks, numberOfShelves;` is not working the way you would expect. You can do `return { "noBooks":numberOfBooks, "noShelf": numberOfShelves};` and use the result as an object from where it is called

Comment: If you click edit, edit above snippet and add relevant HTML, you will have a [mcve]

Comment: Also `window.addEventListener("resize",mainFunc)` if you really want to do this on resize. Note it will execute for every pixel you change the window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the return statement to pass the both values wrapped in object.

```
function getNumberOfShelves(arra, width, imageWidth) {
  var numberOfBooks = (Math.floor(width / widthOfOneImage));
  var numberOfShelves = Math.ceil(arra.length / numberOfBooks);
  console.log(numberOfBooks, numberOfShelves); //work
  return { numberOfBooks, numberOfShelves };
}
```

Change mainFunc to capture the return values, So that you can pass to createManyShelves.

```
function mainFunc() {
  const {numberOfBooks, numberOfShelves} = getNumberOfShelves(arr, document.querySelector('.axis').clientWidth, widthOfOneImage);
  createManyShelves(arr, numberOfBooks, numberOfShelves)
}
```

Also you dont need the global vars

```
var numberOfBooks;
var numberOfShelves;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for you help and the example of how to use destructuring assignment!